# Use Wifi Instead of Bluetooth in game development kit

Tags: wifi, gamekit

I am using GameKit to connect 2 device (peer to peer) way.

I don't want to use bluetooth to connect the devices - I want to use the local wifi router.(the router does not have internet access).

I am able to do every thing using bluetooth but not wifi - I even modified this line:

```
picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
```

to

```
picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby | GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline;
```

but this simple change added a tab saying online, when I tap it it does nothing and when I tap the other tab that says nearby it connects using bluetooth. What's the problem?